# Calculate total value of textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 8 textboxes that only accept integers. How to calculate the total of value entered by users in each textbox and the result will be showed as a label. After user click on submit button, the the value of the label(result of numbers) will be stored in db. Anyone knows? Thank you. Looking forward to hear from u guys. 
I got this error : **Input string was not in a correct format.** 
At this line:

```
int total = 0;
total = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox4.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox6.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox8.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox10.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox12.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox14.Text) + int.Parse(TextBox16.Text);    
Label1.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate this when the form is submitted, or client-side while the user is entering the numbers?

Comment: Way to vague and incomplete. When to (re)calculate the sum? What db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:-

```
totalValue = int.Parse(txtBox1.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox2.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox3.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox4.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox5.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox6.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox7.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox8.Text);
```

Store the value in label

```
label.Text = totalValue;
```

OR

<strike>foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {

            if (c.GetType().Name.ToString()=="TextBox")
           {
                    totalValue += int.Parse(String.Format("txtBox{0}.Text", count));
           }
    }</strike>

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{               
        if (c.GetType().Name.ToString()=="TextBox")
       {
                int value = 0;
                if(int.TryParse(((TextBox)c).Text,out value))
                     totalValue += value;
       }
}
```

Store the value in label

```
label.Text = totalValue;
```

Comment: then, how to dispaly it in label?

Comment: last q, the label which display the total int is at different page. How to pass the valeu to other page?

Comment: @WhoMe you can't ask more questions like this. You create another question and ask what ever your requirement is.

Comment: @WhoMe: On submit, you can pass the result to another page as parameter and get the value using **Request.QueryString**

Comment: `...Name.ToString()` why? Do you want to make *double* sure Name is a string? In Which case you should be super careful. I suggest `Name.ToString().ToString().ToString()` just to be ***sure***

Comment: And another thing, that last code block is just plain *wrong*! `int.Parse(String.Format("txtBox{0}.Text", count))` will just throw a `FormatException`. For an accepted answer this is well below par!

Answer (score 3):

If you can use jQuery add a common class to all the textboxes say "textToCalculate", if the Id of the label is "labelToShowResult"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.textToCalculate').change(function() { 
             var total = 0;

             $('.textToCalculate').each(function(){
              total += parseInt(this.value);
             });

             $('#labelToShowResult').val(total);
        });

     });
</script>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

its simple all you have to do is convert all textbox text to double and than add them with FOR loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 0;
total = int.Parse(txtBox1.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox2.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox3.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox4.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox5.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox6.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox7.Text) + int.Parse(txtBox8.Text);
Label1.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: `int.Parse()` will throw an exception if any of the text boxes are blank. Suggest `int.TryParse()`

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your second question is hold the total value in a parameter and get that value in some other page by using

```
    Request.QueryString
```

for the previous page..
The second way is to keep the total value in a global(static) variable and use it in any of yours page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way :

you can create a void then you can call this void any where in your program or any button.

```
void Calculate_Total()
{
double txt1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox1.Text);
double txt2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox2.Text);
double txt3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox3.Text);
double txt4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox4.Text);
double txt5 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox5.Text);
double txt6 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox6.Text);
double txt7 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox7.Text);
double txt8 = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox8.Text);

double total = txt1 + txt2 + txt3 + txt4 + txt5 + txt6 + txt7 + txt8;

Label1.Text = Convert.Tostring(total);
}
```